# How to use job queue in kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a Flask app where I can upload a file and call a Flask API to process that file using the Python subprocess module (which runs a Shell command).

How to make it work with Kubernetes so that file processing can work with the cluster?

Suppose, I have 2 nodes and each node can process 3 files at a time. so, if I have 10 pending processing. 
6 of them will be done on the 2 nodes and 4 will be in the queue.

I have seen Kubernetes autoscaling but it seems, it will fire as many nodes as needed. If I have a fixed number of nodes and I call my Flask API multiple times, it will be out of resources.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you want to do? What is your specific problem? Where do you plan to store the files when deploying to Kubernetes?

Comment: The files can be anywhere (it is the job of Shell command to find the files). My specific problem is 'Start a pod with the specific Shell command'.  I can simply start a pod when calling the Flask API. But if I call this API 20 times, at the same time, all clusters will be out of resources. If all clusters can run 6 pods at a time (this number can change based on the cluster size), before reaching 90% or 100% CPU/memory usage, the remaining 14 pods will the in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I call this API 20 times, at the same time, all clusters will be out of resources. If all clusters can run 6 pods at a time (this number can change based on the cluster size), before reaching 90% or 100% CPU/memory usage, the remaining 14 pods will the in the queue.

You *can* create [Kubernetes Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) and set the proper value for `parallelism` and `completions` e.g. `parallelism: 6` to have up to 6 pods parallel of this job and `completions: 20` if you have 20 items to process.

**Problems**

But there is several problems with using Kubernetes Jobs for this. First, there is no defined way to allocate input-files to the job-pods, so the job-pods need to have logic for that. And if you don't want to start all 20 jobs at the same time, you better should use a *queue service* to handle a work queue. A queue could be handled by e.g. [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [Nats](https://nats.io/).